# FlowRouter without page reload

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I am following this example https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/rendering-blaze-templates
When I click on my links the whole page is being reloaded. Is there any way to load only the template part that is needed and not the whole page?

Edit: Also I noted another problem. Everything that is outside {{> Template.dynamic}} is being rendered twice.

Here is my project sample. https://github.com/hayk94/UbMvp/tree/routing

EDIT: Putting the contents in the mainLayout template and starting the rendering from there fixed the double render problems. However the reload problems happen because of this code

```
Template.mainLayout.events({
  "click *": function(event, template){
     event.stopPropagation();
     console.log('body all click log');
    //  console.log(c0nnIp);
     var clickedOne = $(event.target).html().toString();
     console.log('This click ' + clickedOne);
     //getting the connID

    var clientIp = null // headers.getClientIP(); // no need for this anymore
    var clientConnId = Meteor.connection._lastSessionId;
    console.log(clientIp);
    console.log(clientConnId);



    Meteor.call("updateDB", {clientIp,clientConnId,clickedOne}, function(error, result){
      if(error){
        console.log("error", error);
      }
      if(result){

      }
    });

  }, // click *
});//events
```

Without this event attached to the template the routing works without any reloads, however as soon as I attach it the problem persists.
Do you have any ideas why this code causes such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2** following question Rev 3:

`event.stopPropagation()` on `"click *"` event probably prevents the router from intercepting the click on link.

Then your browser performs the default behaviour, i.e. navigates to that link, reloading the whole page.

---

**EDIT** following question Rev 2:

Not sure you can directly use your `body` as BlazeLayout target layout.

Notice in the first code sample of [BlazeLayout Usage](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout#usage) that they use an actual template as layout (`<template name="layout1">`), targeted in JS as `BlazeLayout.render('layout1', {});`.

In the tutorial you mention, they similarly use `<template name="mainLayout">`.

That layout template is then appended to your page's body and filled accordingly. You can also change the placeholder for that layout with [`BlazeLayout.setRoot()`](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout#set-different-root-node) by the way.

But strange things may happen if you try to directly target the `body`? In particular, that may explain why you have content rendered twice.

---

Original answer:

If your page is actually reloaded, then your router might not be configured properly, as your link is not being intercepted and your browser makes you actually navigate to that page. In that case, we would need to see your actual code if you need further help.

In case your page does not actually reload, but only your whole content is changed (whereas you wanted to change just a part of it), then you should make sure you properly point your dynamic templates.

You can refer to [`kadira:blaze-layout`](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout) package doc to see how you set up different dynamic template targets in your layout, and how you can change each of them separately (or several of them simultaneously).

You should have something similar in case you use [`kadira:react-layout`](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-react-layout) package.

Comment: Yes, I still need help with this. Please see the edit of my original post.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details. Please note that it is much preferable to paste your code directly into your question, besides linking to your repo. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I added some details in the above answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, I just didn't know where to start debugging my code but now thanks to you I was able to identify the problematic code, I will update the question.

Comment: Maybe `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: yes, that is causing the reloads. Would you please explain me this?